Switch datasources in PowerBI
I manage a server that runs a lot of SSIS packages and an assortment of SQL Job agents.
Due to performance the SSIS log only keeps 10 days of history and the SQL Agents logs about 14 days.
I have created a SSIS packages that saves the SSIS log in a history table so I can see trends over time. I have done the same for the SQL Agent logs.
So SSIS history is copied from  SSISB.catalog.executions into LOGGING.catalog.executions.
SQL job agents history is copied from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory into LOGGING.dbo.sysjobhistory.
All on the same server.
Now I know how to use a parameter to change the datasource: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIq5vN5oPf8
But that technique only allows me to switch all datasource from one database to another (eg from SSISBD -> LOGGING). BUt I need to switch two.
If history is wanted all need to point to LOGGING but if actual data is wanted two databases need to be queried..
How can I arrange with one dropdown that two different databases are queried?
I am thinking along the lines of using one parameter to change two other parameters.
Or some sort of IF statement in the datasource?
Or would it be an idea to make two datasources ? One for SSISDB and one for MSDB?
I have tried several approaches but cannot really find a way on how to do this.
